# What is the meaning of these lines from Speed of Sound by Coldplay?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

In the song Speed of Sound by Coldplay, there are the following lines:

> Every chance that you get,
>   Is a chance you seize

What is the meaning of these lines? Do they mean that **you should seize every chance that you get** or that **only the chances that you actually seize are the chances worth being labeled as the ones you got**?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the declarative (here, "a chance you seize") as a kind of advice-giving, and "you" can be impersonal and mean "one". So, "a chance you seize|a chance one seizes" can be understood as "a chance  one *should* seize or *must* seize".  Compare: "You *don't let* a day go by without smelling the roses."  which is semantically equivalent to "*Never* let...." or "You must not let..."

But to say whether  those lyrics are giving advice is beyond the scope of this site, and would invite only opinion.

That said, I don't think your second possibility is viable, as you must get an opportunity *before* you can seize it.  **you get** there means "you are presented" or "you are given".  We can *get* many opportunities and seize none of them or only a few or only some of them. That we did or did not seize them has no bearing upon whether we *got* them. If you *get a chance* to take a shot on goal, you have gotten the chance whether you take the shot or not.

*You miss 100% of the shots you don't take.*
-- Wayne Gretzky (ice-hockey player)